# Is there an equivalent of iOS navigation controller in BlackBerry-10

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, porting, blackberry-10

I am trying to port an iOS application to BlackBerry-10. Is there anything in BlackBerry-10 that is equivalent to UINavigationController of IOS.

Comment: Not in C++ itself, but probably in the Blackberry UI library. What have you looked at?

Comment: Can you please tell me what library is that?

Comment: There must be documentation you can search.

Comment: I am new at BB10. So dont know much about anything. can you please provide me a link?

Comment: Not to sound rude or anything but it looks to me like you should read some introductory programming books. Your last question can be answered with a google query: "Blackberry UI library".

Comment: Before trying to hardly replicate a pattern, maybe you should start by learning the new platform

Comment: @Leonnears I wanted the link of the page where the equivalent of navigation controller of IOS in BB10 was. I know it could be in the BlackBerry UI Library. But wanted to know which component is the equivalent. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the equivalent is [`NavigationPane`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__navigationpane.html). There's also a [guide on porting your iOS app to BlackBerry 10](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/beta/documentation/porting_ios_intro.html)

Comment: Thanks. This is just the thing I wanted :)

Comment: Can you please tell me where do I find the equivalency list of objective C objects to C++? I have already seen https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/getting_started/porting/objc_cascades.html  But it doesn't seem to contain navigation controller's equivalent or UIView's equivalent and many others.

Comment: There isn't an official list as yet, you'll need to take a look at the Cascades SDK and see which objects fit best with your existing iOS architecture.